# After git reset --hard, why didn’t my topic branch change?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push, git-checkout, git-detached-head

I accidentally rebased my branch with the DEV branch and then pushed it to a remote repository. With the rebase, I selected the current changes and hence my local changes got overwritten.

I lost my earlier commit in the rebase but found it by running `git log`. Then I ran `git checkout commitId` and even `git reset --hard commitId`. However, in both cases my code base still shows the latest rebased code on my branch.

How do I restore my branch back to its previous state?

Comment: Did you commit the local changes that got overridden? If yes, pick a keyword from the changes and try `git log -S <keyword> --reflog` to find out which commit removed the changes.

Comment: Reset moves branch labels about. If you detach HEAD from a branch first, reset won’t have a branch to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Detached What? Dude, Where’s My Commit?

Checking out a commit’s hash or object name enters what the git documentation refers to as [detached HEAD state](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head).

> It is sometimes useful to be able to checkout a commit that is not at the tip of any named branch, or even to create a new commit that is not referenced by a named branch. Let’s look at what happens when we checkout commit *b* (here we show [three] ways this may be done):
>
> ```
> $ git checkout v2.0      # or
> $ git checkout master^^  # or
> $ git checkout b
>
>    HEAD (refers to commit 'b')
>     |
>     v
> a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
>     ^
>     |
>   tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
> ```
>
> Notice that regardless of which checkout command we use, `HEAD` now refers directly to commit *b*. This is known as being in detached HEAD state. It means simply that `HEAD` refers to a specific commit, as opposed to referring to a named branch.

As you observed, git will happily create new commits, rebase, merge, and so on with a detached HEAD, but because no tag or branch refers to the resulting unnamed branch, losing it will be easy. You were able to find your original commit with `git log`. When you have done more drastic surgery, the output of [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is another place to look.

### The Fix

Fixing your branch as described in your question will involve the following sequence.

1. Reattach `HEAD` to your branch (referred to below as `topic/my-branch`)
2. Reset `topic/my-branch` to where it was before
3. Fix `origin/topic/my-branch` from the earlier push.

   - Either do it all at once with a force push, or
   - Delete the old remote branch and push your fixed history

**Reattach HEAD**

Rather than by its SHA-1 hash, check out your branch by name

```
git checkout topic/my-branch
```

**Fix your local branch**

Next, put it back where it was with `git reset --hard`. You will use the same command, but the context is different: `HEAD` after `git checkout` points to `topic/my-branch` rather than to *commitId* directly.

```
git reset --hard commitId
```

**Fix the remote branch**

You said you pushed your rebased branch, so update the remote repository to reflect your changes. The way to do it all in one command is

```
git push --force origin topic/my-branch
```

The administrator of the remote repository may have taken the highly reasonable step of denying force pushes (for why, see below). If so, try a sequence of

1. Delete your branch on the remote side, and then
2. Push your corrected local branch

In the bad old days, we had to delete remote branches with the non-obvious

```
git push origin :topic/my-branch
```

but nowadays, it’s spelled

```
git push --delete origin topic/my-branch
```

Having cleared the way, now push your branch to put things back to where they were before.

```
git push origin topic/my-branch
```

If both force pushes and deletes are disabled on your remote, ask for help from someone with administrative access to that repository.

### Words of Caution

Most of the time, you have to work very hard to convince git to destroy work. However, `git reset --hard`, deleting remote branches, and `git push --force` are all sharp tools — useful when you need them but dangerous when used carelessly. As with `rm -rf`, pause to consider whether you really mean the command you’re about to run.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a minor confusion in the commands order here. If you did

```
git checkout <commitId>
```

it will have detached your `HEAD` then your subsequent

```
git reset --hard <commitId>
```

had no effect since no branch is currently checked out.

Checkout your branch before the reset and it'll be ok :

```
git checkout <yourBranchName>
git reset --hard <commitId>
```

Comment: It's not that `git reset --hard` has *no* effect after checking out a commit hash. It's just that it does not affect any *branch name* since there is no current branch. You still move to the selected commit, erasing any uncommitted work—so that `git reset --hard <hash>` is a lot like another `git checkout <hash>` except that the latter will leave uncommitted modifications to the index and work-tree alone, at the expense of failing the `git checkout` in some cases.

Comment: @torek I was meaning that is has "no effect *on the branch*", but you're right, let's avoid misunderstandings.